# TestNG Appium Paralell Runs Organization

Tags: parallel-processing, structure, testng, appium

I'm trying to create a testNG suite for running tests using Appium concurrently on multiple devices. I'm currently using an @BeforeSuite to setup the server/driver for each device, and then distributing the connections to test methods using @BeforeMethod and @AfterMethod functions. I have a master suite-of-suite .xml that calls down to different child .xml files associated with each of my test classes. The test classes are each associated with a @Factory, which allows me to run the instances in parallel (decided at run-time based on the number of attached devices).

**Parent**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Default Suite">
  <parameter name="other" value="@SOMETHING@"></parameter>
  <suite-files>
    <suite-file path="src/first.xml" />
    <suite-file path="src/second.xml" />
  </suite-files>
</suite>
```

**Child**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="first" parallel="instances">
  <test name="android">
    <classes>
      <class name="TestFactory" />
    </classes>
  </test>
</suite>
```

**Factory**

```
public class TestFactory {

    @Factory
    public Object[] initial() {
        int numDevices = DeviceManager.getNumAttachedDevices();
        Object[] result = new Object[numDevices];
        for (int i = 0; i < numDevices; i++) {
            result[i] = new StartupTest();
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

I definitely don't want to do this. It seems pretty ridiculous that I need to create a new @Factory class for each of the test classes that I want. I found out recently that I can use parallel=true inside of a @DataProvider, which can be used together with paralell="methods" and an annotation transformer for invocationCount in order to achieve a similar result (one method running for each of the attached devices).

I'm not sure how my @BeforeMethod and @AfterMethod calls can be used to do the required setup and cleanup on the correct device (they would be missing the device name). Is there any other recommended way for doing this? Or is this my best option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I can use my @Factory method inside of the test class, instead of making a separate class altogether.

As far as I can tell, it's not simple to control the TestNG threads on parallel="methods" so that they all join after running a single method. Without that capability, it seems a lot more complicated (and not worthwhile) to use @DataProvider.

Inside of my @Factory I can still pass custom arguments for each of the instances.